# Need steps to build & update an existing jar file using Gradle

Tags: gradle, build, executable-jar

enter image description hereI am a new to using Gradle.

Need steps to build & update an existing `gradle-wrapper.jar` file using gradle **[update the JDK update version]**. Need to update the JDK version from **8u144** to **8u171**.

Note that this jar is part of a sample application.

Gradle install is successful & i am able to run the **gradle -v command**.

At which location should the ‘**gradle-wrapper.jar**’ be placed?

Should i create a **build.gradle & add** any lines of code in them?

Thanks,
Kunal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psyMN.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Za0iC.png)

Comment: Have you run `gradle init`?

Comment: Hi, I did following steps:
1. download the entire source code folder & run the gradle init command.
2. Received the errors related to Android SDK licenses as in the screenshot in thread above.
3. After that ran the following cmds : sdkmanager.bat "platforms;android-28"    and  sdkmanager.bat –licenses, but ended with errors.

Do suggest steps to overcome these Android SDK licenses errors & how to update the executable jar file named gradle-wrapper.jar ?
I have Java 8 Update 251 on my laptop.

Thanks